# Appending Parent form Record based on Value in Subform with Multiple Records

Tags: ms-access, append, subform

I have an append query that runs on the on click event of a button on my parent form.

The query only appends the current record if a text field in the sub form meets a specific criteria. The query seems to operate as intended other than the criteria is only evaluated on the first sub form record.

How can I get the criteria to search all current sub form records and append the record if the criteria is met?

-Parent Form: Primary_frm
-Sub Form: Review_sfrm
-Field being evaluated: Review_sfrm.Desc
-Table appending to: Editied_records_tbl

Query below (table and field names have been changed):

```
 INSERT INTO Edited_records_tbl
    SELECT Record_number 
    FROM Records_tbl
    WHERE ID =Forms!Primary_frm!Review_sfrm.Form.ID and Forms!Primary_frm!Review_sfrm.Form.Desc = "xxxx";
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access, subform controls are generated for only one record at a time. This means you have to iterate over the subform to append all records.

You can use the following code from the main form.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
With Me.Review_sfrm.Form
   DoCmd.SetWarnings False
   Set rs = .RecordsetClone 'Get underlying subform records
   rs.MoveFirst 'Start at first record
   Do Until rs.EOF 'Until last record
       .Bookmark = rs.Bookmark 'Navigate to current record
       DoCmd.OpenQuery "MyQuery"
       rs.MoveNext 'Next record
    Loop
End With
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: I will give your solution a try when I get back to work next week. Appending all the sub form records will work since the field I will be appending is not unique in the sub form, but will be the PK in the table I am appending to. However, out of curiosity, is it possible to use a similar method to append only the sub form record that met a given criteria?

Comment: Yes, of course. Inside the loop looping over the subform, you can test for any given criterium, or you can use `.FindFirst` instead of `.MoveFirst`, `.NoMatch` instead of `.EOF` and `.FindNext` with your criterium instead of `.MoveNext`

Comment: This portion of the code 'CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery").Execute is throwing a 'too few parameters' error. The expressions in your solution are outside my limited knowledgebase so my trouble shooting efforts are limited.

Comment: @k1234 Try the current edit. Because you're relying on form-based parameters the more direct way of executing queries runs into trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your solution effectively accomplishes the intended task. When I played around with the options you presented in the second comment rs.FindDirst and rs.FindNext both returned "Argument Not Optional" errors, but it is irrelevant since the primary solution works.